# Vertical alignment issue after setting attributedText on a cell's detailTextLabel

Tags: ios, uitableview, nsattributedstring

I am using the default right detail `UITableViewCell` style so I can provide a title and a value on the right. I would like to utilize an `NSAttributedString` for the detail's text so that I can prepend a small $ symbol in front of a number. While this does work, it has caused the cell's `textLabel` to be pushed up higher and the `detailTextLabel` lower, so they’re not vertically centered in the cell anymore.

Do you know why setting a cell's `detailTextLabel`’s `attributedText` to a string that is simply two different font sizes would cause that to occur, and what can I do to resolve this?

```
UITableViewCell *cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleValue1 reuseIdentifier:@"cell"];

cell.textLabel.text = @"Paid to Agent";

NSMutableAttributedString *attributedString = [[NSMutableAttributedString alloc] initWithString:@"$" attributes:@{NSFontAttributeName: [UIFont systemFontOfSize:10]}];
[attributedString appendAttributedString:[[NSAttributedString alloc] initWithString:@"2000" attributes:@{NSFontAttributeName: [UIFont systemFontOfSize:17]}]];
cell.detailTextLabel.attributedText = attributedString;
```

[image]

Comment: never noticed that kind of behaviour but what about creating your own custom tableviewcell? it's pretty simple...

Comment: I prefer custom cells than the default one but have you tried to make a tableViewCell a bit higher? maybe it doesn't fit one under another and that is the case.

Comment: Thanks, a custom `UITableViewCell` subclass worked fine - just a bit of a pain to recreate something that's provided for free. :p